# Mexican Hat Function that Converges to 1

Tags: functions, wavelets

The Ricker wavelet, also known as the Mexican Hat function, converges to 0 for negative and positive infinity.

[image: plot of the Mexican Hat function]

I'm looking for a function with the same shape in the center, but that converges back to 1 (or a value really close to 1) when approaching negative or positive infinity.

P.S: Obviously $f(x) + 1$ does not work, as the new maximum will be close to 2.

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by "same shape in the center"?

Comment: Adding a function that is very close to 0 around 0 but goes to 1 in either direction will work, depending on what you want to preserve in the center. Something like  1- a wide multiple of a normal curve or something?

Comment: By "same shape in the center" I mean it has around the same values/derivatives in the [-2.5ish, 2.5ish] range (looking at this image).

Comment: See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4utprhqvmt) of user113102's suggested function. You can change the values of $s$ and $d$ using the slider. Larger $s$ and larger $d$ (an even integer) will match the original function better close to the origin.

Comment: That really looks great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work:
$$f(x)=1-0.1e^{-0.36x^2}-1.3x^2e^{-x^2}$$

Comment: How did you get to this function?